# Inheriting a Visual Studio Solution from a base solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution file that is under source control and I want to extend this to another solution containing more projects than the original one. However, I would like to have the changes made to the original solution to affect my extended solution every time the source is updated.

Is this possible?

Comment: I am very curious about this as well.  Has anyone found a way to do this?

Comment: @JamesEggers my answer below

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152684/visual-studio-how-to-make-one-solution-depend-on-another

Comment: Depending on what you really want to do you could benefit from Solution Filters (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/load-only-the-projects-you-need-with-solution-filters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/filtered-solutions) a relatively (VS2019) new feature.

Answer (score 3):

This was possible 15 years ago.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/habibh/walkthrough-adding-an-existing-visual-studio-solution-to-another-solution

Recent versions of Visual Studio don't have this functionality anymore.
However the .NET SDK has a new tool
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln

> dotnet sln

It provides various commands to manipulate solution files, including adding and removing projects, listing projects, and more.

You can combine it with Powershell to basically do whatever you want.
For example, the following script extracts the projects from a solution file and adds them to another solution:

```
function Merge-Solution([string]$SolutionName, [string]$TargetSolution)
{    
    $AllProjects = Get-AllProjects -TargetSolution $TargetSolution

    foreach($project in $AllProjects)
    {
        if (Test-Path $project -PathType Leaf) {
            &dotnet.exe sln $SolutionName add $project
        }        
    }
}

function Get-AllProjects([string]$TargetSolution)
{
    $AllProjects += Get-ProjectsInSolution($TargetSolution)
    $AllProjects | Select-Object -Unique
}

function Get-ProjectsInSolution([string]$TargetSolution)
{
    $solutionDirectory = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($TargetSolution)
    $solutionListing = &dotnet.exe sln $TargetSolution list | Select-Object -Skip 2

    foreach($project in $solutionListing )
    {
        $relativePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($solutionDirectory, $project)
        [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($relativePath)
    }
}

$originalSolutionPath = "C:\OriginalSolution.sln"
$targetSolutionPath = "C:\TargetSolution.sln"

Merge-Solution -SolutionName $originalSolutionPath -TargetSolution $targetSolutionPath
```

Comment: This is great and provides a great solution for me to use and adapt for my needs.  Thanks!!

Comment: You can integrate this kind of scripts into your CI/CD pipelines or as git pre-commit hooks and basically do whatever you want. Just be creative :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use .props or .target files. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/project-property-inheritance?view=msvc-170