# What criteria should be used in deciding whether or not to create another Visual Studio Project (.NET)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, namespaces, projects-and-solutions

I have a large solution with around a hundred projects. Some people say it's too much, other people say it could be ok. The root of the question really is what criteria should be used in deciding whether or not to create another Visual Studio Project, as opposed to using one that already exists? What's the best practice?

For example:

1) Should I create a new project when adding a new feature that is somewhat independent of other existing features? Would this be a right or wrong reason to create a new project. Should namespaces here be used instead?

2) Should I create a new project when developing another tier or layer (the classic Data Access, Business, Presentation layers). Should namespaces here be used instead?

3) Should I create new projects to separate my interfaces from my implementation. Is this enough of a reason to create a new project?

Etc. These sub questions don't really need to be answered specifically, but this is the kind of criteria I'm looking for.

Thanks

Comment: too subjective. There is no one right answer. I could answer Yes or No to points 1, 2, or 3 and justify my reasoning, I would be right (partially) in both cases.

Comment: Assemblies are the smallest unit of independently versionable code. Do you need the code in all these projects to be independently versioned?

Comment: @jodrell I know there is no right answer. That's why I'm looking for a list of criteria. I would then take that list and apply it to different cases. I was also hoping, but maybe that's not possible, to have a list based on proven practices as opposed to just what everyone does.

Comment: What it comes down to is a solution and project are simply **views** into the code. My rule of thumb is that when code/assemblies/libraries no longer need to be viewed, make them into prebuilt libraries or even localized nu-get packages (way cool). So simply ask yourself, do all these projects need to be viewed and changed on a regular basis? If not, break out functionality into linkable libraries.

Comment: @Mark, forigive my lack of clarity, when I say "there is no right answer" I mean there is no finite list of criteria sufficiently encompassing to enable a consistenet choice across the majority of projects. Since you gave no example, what else could I have meant?

Comment: I think a good answer can be given here. I think there is research and work done on this. It is not an infinite list of criteria. Upon further research I see that these things have been analyzed and thought through. I summary can be given on stackoverflow without it being opinion based but based on what practically works and leads to good design. Here is such an article http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AssemblyFiefdomsWhatsTheRightNumberOfAssembliesLibraries.aspx. Here is a research paper done on this topic. http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/granularity.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Basically I would say that you need to create a new project when you need to create a new assembly that will be used by at least 2 assemblies, for the rest just use the namespaces.

For example, say you have a business logic layer, and it is used in 2 different applications that share some common rules, you can create a new project.
If later you want to add new rules specific to other projects, you can still use the namespace `BusinessLogic` but create a new project.

The thing is to understand the use of namespaces and assemblies. To me:

- Namespaces are useful to separate concerns, like BusinessLogic shouldn't be in the same namespace as DataAccess.
- Assemblies are useful for technical reasons, like I want to use this assembly in other assemblies.

By following these definitions you can easily refactor your code, or create a new assembly from existing code that needs to be used elsewhere after some time without changing your namespaces and editing existing working code.

To answer your specific questions:

1) If this is a "pluggable" feature that will be instantiated dynamically then yes, if not you don't need to do it (I don't say it would be bad though)

2) Namespaces should be used anyway

3) Here I would say yes if you instantiate your implementations dynamically, otherwise namespaces would do the job

Answer (score 0):

For maintaining these large no. of projects, use **`Solution Folders`** which are used to group projects that fall into same functionality, layer, tier, See [Using Solution Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sx2027y2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Also see these articles and SO QA for help reference and suggestions on structuring solution and projects in `Visual Studio`:

[How to structure Visual Studio solutions](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.in/2007/07/how-to-structure-visual-studio.html)

See new VS tool: [Layered Architecture Solution Guidance 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2dc87fb2-d6f2-4151-9dab-faad717eea41)

[Solution: Per application, or per application suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200954/solution-per-application-or-per-application-suite#201064)

[The Ultimate Visual Studio Solution Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516313/the-ultimate-visual-studio-solution-structure)

[Structuring Solutions in Visual Studio and Team Foundation](http://keithelder.net/2007/02/01/Structuring-Solutions-in-Visual-Studio-and-Team-Foundation/)